# How do I check custom TURN server is working with easyRTC

Tags: node.js, turn, easyrtc

I am working on an application for Audio/Video calls using easyrtc.
I have added turn server details in server.js file to configure the turn servers I want to use.

```
var myIceServers = [
  {url: "stun:stun.anyfirewall.com:3478"},
  {url: "turn:turn.anyfirewall.com:443", "username":"xxxxx", "credential":"xxxxx"},
  {url: "turn:turn.anyfirewall.com:443?transport=tcp", "username":"xxxxx", "credential":"xxxxx"}
];
```

then set options for appIceServers using below line of code.

```
easyrtc.setOption("appIceServers", myIceServers);
```

and configured the listener as well.

```
easyrtc.on("getIceConfig", function(connectionObj, callback){
  callback(null, myIceServers);
}
```

After this when I am running easyrtc simple audio-video demo, from local machine, in chrome using two tabs it works fine.

**Now I have two questions**:

1. How do I make sure that easyrtc is using custom supplied TURN server configuration ?
2. And from where I need to test the links for my application, which will make sure that easyrtc is using custom supplied TURN url for tcp ? (i.e. firewall check).

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the "log level" to "3" in server.js to see more detail logs, and use chrome://werbrtc-internals to see the chrome webrtc logs . I just set up a TURN server yesterday and in my way , I modified the easyrtc_default_options to using my own TURN,I think your configuration will work if you test with two client in different network, the Turn server will give you a feedback.

"from local machine, in chrome using two tabs it works fine." this is not using you TURN server.

Comment: I have setup turn and put configuration at `easyrtc_default_options` but I am getting this error message `uncaught exception: buildPeerConnection failed, call not completed`